# Ack with regex - Confusion with simple queries

Tags: regex, ack

I am trying to use [ack-is-better-than-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) (ack) with regular expressions to find lines and snippets in my code repository. My understanding is that ack uses [Perl-derivative regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derivative_regular_expressions), is that correct?

However, I am not sure how would these queries work:

```
ack 'foo'
ack '.*(foo)+.*'

ack '.*foo'
ack 'foo.*'
```

Could they give different outputs? If so, why?

**EDIT:** In my tests they output different results (the first one outputs more matches than the others, for example). They also highlight different parts of the same lines.

**EDIT 2:** The difference in the output apparently is related to the highlighting (the coloring of the output). I have noticed that if I run `ack` with `--nocolor` the output of the commands above are the same. Apparently running `ack` with the default coloring makes part of the output invisible in my machine/config. I am running it on a GNOME terminal from bash in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: *Do* these queries give different outputs? If so, can you please give an example? Otherwise, what is your reason to suspect that they do?

Comment: What do you mean by the first one outputs more matches? Which lines are matched by 1 but not matched by the others?

Comment: Thanks @Konrad and @inTide, I have updated the question to address your comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> My understanding is that ack uses Perl-derivative regular expressions, is that correct?

Yes. In fact, `ack` is *written in Perl* and just forwards the expressions to the internal engine.

> Could they give different outputs? If so, why?

The expressions should find the same results. However, the output might still differ since `ack` allows syntax highlighting in its output (by default; unless `--nocolor` is specified) – it uses ANSI escape codes to colour hits in the output and obviously `'foo'` will highlight up something different than `'.*foo'` (and the other queries).

Namely, in the following input:

```
This is a foo test.
```

a query for `'foo'` will highlight just that: “`foo`”, while `'.*foo'` will highlight “`This is a foo`”.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad, that explains the differences in highlighting. I do however get different outputs for them, BUT when I run them with the `--nocolor` option they do output the same result. I think the problem is that there is a problem with the ANSI escape codes in some of the outputs that makes the matchings invisible (there is black space in the output for some of them)